# Highcharts export module in Nodejs script

Tags: node.js, highcharts

I have installed highcharts-export-server globally using this command:

```
 npm install highcharts-export-server -g
```

But when I run my nodejs script this command:

```
require('highcharts-export-server');
```

Gives me an error: Cannot find module 'highcharts-export-server'

Am I missing more installation steps?

Thanks

Comment: I would think to install it locally to the project ... then check the node modules folder for it .. 

You could always open the JSON package file and view its entry point

Comment: And by locally you mean npm install highcharts-export-server in the project folder?

Comment: Yup so 
 npm install highcharts-export-server 

without the -g

Comment: Now I am trying using export server as Node.js Module described here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server. I have created a JS file with their example code. How can I test it? I have never done nodejs before. How would I invoke their example code?

Comment: Well on pure node js  you would probably be able to test it on the command line . but Im sure you want to see the result in a web page so you would need express to view in a webpage 

the command to get it to run is " npm start ": defined in the json package file ...

Node.js on it own is only the language plugin . you have to set up the server yourself through express or react etc ...https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html